# Display symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post, twig

I have a problem with form.

For start, in my main twig I include the twig i use for the form:

```
 {% include 'MainBundle::manage.html.twig'%}
```

The controller is mainController

The controller displays everything that appears in main twig.

The action of the form :

```
public function manageAction(Request $request){

        $manageForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('submitFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'File to Submit'))
        ->add('send', SubmitType::class)->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod('post') == 'POST') {
            // Bind request to the form
            $manageForm->bindRequest($request);

            // If form is valid
            if ($manageForm->isValid()) {
                // Get file
                $file = $manageForm->get('submitFile');

                $file->getData();
            }

        }
        return $this->render('MainBundle::main.html.twig', array(
            'manageForm' => $manageForm->createView()
        ));
    }
```

routing.yml

```
manage:
    path: /manage
    defaults:
      _controller: MainBundle:Main:manage
    requirements:
      _method: POST
```

manage.html.twig

```
{% extends 'MainBundle::main.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
        {{ form_widget(manageForm) }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

when i run in the route /main I should have my form display but i have an error

> Variable "manageForm" does not exist.

I guess the controller does not take the view...

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case - change to following.

```
return $this->render('MainBundle::manage.html.twig', array(
        'manageForm' => $manageForm->createView()
    ));
```

If you extend the main/base twig in other twig, then you need to render this other twig (always).

Parameters which you pass to extended twig will be available **in twig you have extended** (in this case the main.html.twig), but it doesn't work the other way around.

```
{% include 'MainBundle::manage.html.twig'%} // why ?
```

**Don't do anything with main - just extend it in manage!!!!**

**I see other problems with your overall code also.**

**CONTROLLER:**
         // the more modern way instead of checking manually for request method

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
      // perform actions...
    } else {
       // was not valid...return error messages 
     }
}
```

**FORM**

```
<form action="" method="post"> // this is the oldschool way
    {{ form_widget(manageForm) }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Better something like... (some of my recent coded examples)

```
  {{ form_start(form, {'attr' : {'method' : 'post', 'enctype' : 'multipart/form-data', 'class' : 'test'}}) }}
         {{ form_errors(form.resume) }}
         {{ form_widget(form.resume, {'attr' : {'id' : 'file-upload-rec', 'class' : 'file-upload-rec js-file-upload-rec', 'accept' : '.pdf, .doc, .docx'}}) }}
         {{ form_label(form.resume, 'select', {'label_attr' : {'class' : 'file-upload js-file-upload'}}) }}
         {{ form_row(form._token) }}
  {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

ps. you might also want to read all of https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering `main.html.twig` instead of `manage.html.twig`. I guess the first one uses an `importForm` variable which is therefore not passed to the view.

If not, and you really need to render `main.html.twig` which includes `manage.html.twig`, then why is `manage.html.twig` extending `main.html.twig`? Either include one in another, or extend one from another, not both.

Comment: Sorry it's not the good error, the error is "Variable "manageForm" does not exist."
if i change the render it's the same error..

Comment: Did you also remove the include from your main.html.twig ? No need for include in it, if your manage template is extending main one

Comment: But how will it be displayed if I do not include it in the main twig ?

Comment: You dont include it in main. You extend the main from your manage.

Comment: You are extending it in your manage.html.twig. Just add {{ parent() }} in your content block to retrieve everything from the parent (main.html.twig) template's content block. Check this for reference : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html

Comment: thanks for your help... But when i add parent i have : Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, I took the time to read the documentations and I understood now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable while including your template

```
{% include 'MainBundle::manage.html.twig' with {'manageForm': manageForm} %}
```

For more information see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think he wants to do this - only if he wants the form to be displayed in all pages. 

Considering his main template contains navigation for example.

Comment: In his question he says Variable "manageForm" does not exist." And the reason for this is mentioned in my answer. That's another debate if his design is suitable for what he intends to do.Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I see man, but he is doing and thinking wrong. 

Usually you define one base/main template, then you extend it and place the unique content per page in each of extended templates.

Comment: I understand your point, which is right. I just answered the cause of error. Thanks!